# URL Rewrite and Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

Im fairly new to Wordpress development and i have run into a problem.

We recently launched a new site made in Wordpress. On our old site we had a rule in htaccess that rederected traffic from /ABC123 to /bil.php?regno=ABC123. The rule was "any URL that ends with /XXXNNY where X is a letter, N is a number and Y i either redirects to /bil.php?regno=XXXNNY".

Here is the htaccess rule from the old page:

```
# If formated like ABC123 or ABC12A
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z]{3}[0-9]{2}[A-Za-z0-9])$ bil.php?regno=$1 [L]
```

Now, I need the same redirect rule on our new Wordpress site (except it should redirect to /begagnad-bil/?regnr=XXX123).

Adding the rule above to the htaccess file doesn't work.

I also tried adding the following code to the beginning of my functions.php file inside the theme folder.

```
add_action( 'init', 'pmg_rewrite_add_rewrites' );
function pmg_rewrite_add_rewrites()
{
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^([A-Za-z]{3}[0-9]{2}[A-Za-z0-9])$',
        '/begagnad-bil/?regnr=$1',
        'top'
    );
}
```

...but this doesn't work either.

edit: I also flush the rules by clicking Save under Settings -> Permalinks in the Wordpress admin.

How would one do such a redirect on a Wordpress site?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the 301 directive at the end of your rule like so

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z]{3}[0-9]{2}[A-Za-z0-9])$ begagnad-bil/?regnr=$1  [R=301,L]
```